# ¿Porque no se produce el background-image en laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, sass

resulta que quiero colocar una imagen de fondo a una pagina web , y estoy usando laravel, resulta que al colocar el codigo de "background-image" , no me carga la imagen o probablemente no lo encuentra, tengo la carpeta "images" dentro de la carpeta public , y desde hay lo llamo , pero no me produce nada , de antemano muchas gracias, adjuntare el codigo e imagenes de referencia de directorio:

code css:

```css
body{
    background-image: url("/public/images/hot-air-balloon-2411851.png");
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100vh;

}
```

Imagenes de referencia directorio :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No deberías hacer referencia a la carpeta public xq ya estas dentro de ella, debería quedar así

background-image: url('/template/assets/images/line-vertical.png');

Comment: Es que resulta que estoy poniendo el codigo css en un precompilador que es sass , por eso llamo al public , el archivo sass esta en resources/sass/app.scss , desconozco si esto produce algun tipo de error, aplica lo mismo que mencionaste en este caso? ,Muchas gracias por comentar!